# What's the intuition behind a split exact sequence?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I've learned the following definition for a split exact sequence:

A short exact sequence of $R$-module homomorphisms $0\to A \stackrel{f}{\to} B \stackrel{g}{\to} C \to 0$ is split if there exists a homomorphism $\alpha:B\to A$ such that $\alpha\circ f = 1$ or a homomorphism $\beta:C\to B$ such that $g\circ \beta = 1$.

I can never remember whether the definition requires $\alpha\circ f = 1$ or $f \circ \alpha = 1$, and similarly for the other mapping, $\beta$. I suspect that my inability to remember this stems from an underlying lack of understanding about what split exact sequences are for, what a sequence being split really tells us about the modules and morphisms involved, and what concept split exact sequences are meant to capture or generalize.

Is there a good way to remember the directions of composition for these definitions?

What is the intuition, utility, and underlying meaning behind a split exact sequence?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The direction of the maps for splitting is always in the *opposite direction* of the original maps. So you should think of "splitting" as being able to reverse the sequence to obtain $0\to C\to B\to A\to 0$. In terms of the order, you always end up with identity maps *on the end*. So to split is to have $A\to B\to A$ being the identity on $A$, and to have $C\to B\to C$ being the identity on $C$. In particular, your example would have $\alpha\circ f=\mathbb{1}_A$.

Intuitively, at least in the finitely generated case, $B$ is "bigger" than $A$ and $C$, so we cannot find an injection from $B$ to $A$ or a surjection from $C$ to $B$, so we cannot hope for the maps to be composed in the opposite order to obtain the identity on $B$.

The way I think of splitting is that a split exact sequence $0\to A\to B\to C\to 0$ is one for which there is a (possibly non-canonical) isomorphism $B\cong A\oplus C$, and for which $f$ and $g$ look like the "natural" maps into and from a direct sum, i.e. inclusion and projection. Thus the sequence looks like 
$$
0\to A\to A\oplus C\to C\to 0.
$$
In particular, the sections now look like inclusion into one factor, $c\to (0,c)$, or projection onto another factor, $(a,c)\to a$.

Comment: Can you explain briefly the meaning of "sequence split but NON-canonical"? "NON-canonical" means that $B \neq A \oplus C$, but it splits so it means? pardon me, thanks

Answer (score 5):

When you have a short exact sequence

$$ 0 \to A \xrightarrow{f} B \xrightarrow{g} C \to 0 $$

$B$ canonically has a submodule $\mathrm{im}(f) \cong A$ and a quotient module $\mathrm{coim}(f) \cong C$. When the sequence is *split*, we can actually write $B$ as a direct sum of these two modules, which lets us decompose the given short exact sequence into a direct sum of two short exact sequences:

$$
 \begin{matrix} 
0 \to A \xrightarrow{f} &B& \xrightarrow{g}  C \to 0 
\\ & \cong
\\ 0 \to A \xrightarrow{f} &\mathrm{im}(f)& \to0 \to 0 
\\ & \oplus
\\ 0 \to 0 \to & \mathrm{coim}(g) & \xrightarrow{g} C \to 0 
\end{matrix}$$

I imagine this is where the term *split* comes from.

A splitting $\beta$ of the epimorphism $g$ is meant to be the *monic* map expressing how $\mathrm{coim}(g)$ is being made into a submodule of $B$ in a way compatible with $g$. So $g \circ \beta = 1_C$.

Similarly for the splitting $\alpha$ of the monomorphism $f$.

---

Having a pair of morphisms

$$ Y \xrightarrow{u} X \xrightarrow{v} Y $$
with $v \circ u = 1_Y$ is a significant phenomenon going by lots of names coming from lots of mathematical settings. For example:

- $v$ is a left inverse of $u$
- $u$ is a right inverse of $v$
- $u$ is a split monomorphism, with $v$ its splitting
- $v$ is a split epimorphism, with $u$ its splitting
- $u$ is a section of $v$
- We say that $Y$ is a retract of $X$, given by the retraction $(u,v)$
- $u \circ v$ is a split idempotent, with the splitting given by $(u,v)$